# Web scraping with Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, web-scraping, mechanize, racket

Is there a good library/package to do web scraping using Scheme (preferably Racket)?

e.g. a Scheme equivalent of [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)?

Comment: Valid HTML (read XML) can be easily parsed into S-expressions.

Comment: Right, but what about submitting html forms, navigating links, etc.?

Comment: I am sure Racket has some http-client / web-client libraries.

Comment: I haven't yet found a good mechanize-style library for Racket.

Comment: What about a "not-so-good" one? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used a combination of the Racket [net/url](http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/url.html) library, the [html-parsing package](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=html-parsing.plt&owner=neil), and [SXML](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=sxml2.plt&owner=clements) (especially `sxpath`, for XPath queries). Actually, I wrote [some wrappers](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/ryanc/webapi.plt/1/1/private/net.rkt) around net/url that make it slightly easier to use, IMO.

When I've needed to handle cookies, I've called out to the `curl` command instead of using net/url.